# Google Visualization API: Format mysql result with cross tabulation

Tags: mysql, arrays, google-visualization

i'm new to google apps script and i'm trying to visualize data using the Google Visualization API.
I have been able to display a table from the good examples given on mixing php and html. But the database does not seem to have the right format for the column charts.

The table has the colums 'day' 'user' 'task' 'hours' and the data is then being pushed into the rows underneath by a while loop:

```
$table1 = array();
$table1['cols'] = array(

// Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles.
array('label' => 'day', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'user', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'task', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'hours', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$temp = array();
// each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
 $temp[] = array('v' => $r['day']);
 $temp[] = array('v' => $r['user']);
 $temp[] = array('v' => $r['task']);
 $temp[] = array('v' => $r['hours']);

// insert the temp array into $rows
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
// populate the table with rows of data
 $table1['rows'] = $rows;
```

giving me a table like this:

```
day     user    task    hours
monday  user1   wash    3
monday  user2   clean   2
monday  user3   iron    4
tuesday user1   clean   4
tuesday user2   iron    1
tuesday user3   wash    3
```

What i actually need is a table like this:

```
day     user1  user2  user3  clean  iron  wash
monday  3      2      4      2      4     3
tuesday 4      1      3      4      1     3
```

I know the list of users in advance.

EDIT: The issue is '(server side) cross tabulation' as i'm seeing in [this link](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/12/04/crosstabs.html).
I'm trying to figure it out and would still be glad for every help and will of couse mark answers as such.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the list of users and tasks ahead of time, or are those values dynamic from query to query?

Comment: Yes I know the list of users in advance. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Is each user/task the sum total of all time spent per day?  As an example, if both `user1` and `user2` spent time on `clean` on Monday, would the `clean` column be the sum of both, or would you expect two different entries?

Comment: The tasks per day should be summed up. In your example clean would be the sum of both users from that monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the format you need, the easiest way is to pivot your data in the MySQL query.  MySQL doesn't support pivots, but you can fake it like this:

```
SELECT
    day,
    SUM(IF(user = 'user1', hours, 0)) as user1,
    SUM(IF(user = 'user2', hours, 0)) as user2,
    SUM(IF(user = 'user3', hours, 0)) as user3,
    SUM(IF(task = 'clean', hours, 0)) as clean,
    SUM(IF(task = 'iron', hours, 0)) as iron,
    SUM(IF(task = 'wash', hours, 0)) as wash
FROM myTable
GROUP BY day
```

Then build your DataTable with a column for each user and task:

```
$table1 = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('label' => 'day', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'user1', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'user2', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'user3', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'clean', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'iron', 'type' => 'number'),
        array('label' => 'wash', 'type' => 'number')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table1['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => $r['day']),
        array('v' => $r['user1']),
        array('v' => $r['user2']),
        array('v' => $r['user3']),
        array('v' => $r['clean']),
        array('v' => $r['iron']),
        array('v' => $r['wash'])
    ));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot asgallant, i'm trying to apply your sollution to my script.

Comment: I tested your code with a test database and it works!! thank you a lot, i'll mark you as answer!