# SO's answers to dynamic pivoting causes 'Error in SQL Synthax'

Tags: mysql, dynamic, pivot

I have tried every fitting answer on dynamic pivoting and i always end up with the following error when executing the code at once:

> QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT day , ', @sql, ' FROM my_table GROUP BY day');
>   ' at line 6

I'm working on an Amazon AWS with MYSQL 5.1.63 installed and my prepared statement is the following code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(case when user = ''', user, ''' then hours end)
    AS ', user))
    INTO @sql
    FROM my_table;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT day , ', @sql, '
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY day');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

My view looks like this:

```
day     user    task    hours
monday  user1   wash    3
monday  user2   clean   2
monday  user3   iron    4
tuesday user1   clean   4
tuesday user2   iron    1
tuesday user3   wash    3
```

and should be dynamically pivoted to this:

```
day     user1  user2  user3 
monday  3      2      4      
tuesday 4      1      3
```

I have tried executing the query bit by bit and this way the error come with the 'prepare'-line:

> QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 FROM eee_alltime GROUP BY mon'
>   at line 7
>   Query is: sql : 'PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

Anybody got a tip on what it could be that i'm doing wrong?

I have tried the code on a table (not a view) on the same database and it also does'nt work and i can't reproduce the error on Fiddle.

Comment: The syntax you are using appears to be MySQL, yet you've tagged this with both MySQL and SQL Server. What database are you using?  I'd also suggest writing your query as a static version first, then convert it to dynamic SQL to make sure that you get the syntax correct.  This would help solve some issues.

Comment: I think something to do with this line: DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(case when user = ''', user, ''' then hours end), you are using extra quotes both sides.

Comment: @juergen d: thanks for editing.

Comment: @bluefeet i have already written a static version of the pivoted table in my [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743627/google-visualization-api-format-mysql-result-with-cross-tabulation). But that does not brake down the problem for me to be honest.

Comment: @avisheks: The error message does not change wheter i use three, two or just one quote. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: @BrianQ where are you getting the error?  I'm not reproducing it on sql fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/643540/1.  I'm also confused at why you are transposing both the `users` and the `task` to columns, there is no way to determine which `user` and `task` are related when you convert them to columns.

Comment: Please add the error you'r getting, and also try reproducing it on fiddle, so that we can have a look together

Comment: @bluefeet actually this is exactly the conversion i need. The table on top does not require the tasks in columns. I can't reproduce the error in Fiddle. Im working with an Amazon AWS with MYSQL 5.1 installed. I've already changed the MYSQL version in Fiddle.

Comment: @avisheks: The error is 
>QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the >manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right >syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(case >when user = ''', user, ' at line 2
>Query is:...

The query is still the same as seen on top. I'll try to reproduce the error and report.

Thank you all for your support!!

Comment: I'm working with a view created from two tables. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in the column 'user' one entry was '1' which produced the error.

@avisheks: I was able to reproduce the error in [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/940c9/5) and solved by adding a where clause in the select statement because i only want usernames that include 'user' listed:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(case when user = ''', user, ''' then hours end)
    AS ', user))
    INTO @sql
    FROM my_table WHERE user LIKE '%user%';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT day , ', @sql, '
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY day');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Have a look at [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2797/4).
Thanks a lot avisheks and bluefeet for making me use fiddle for error-reproduction!